# inserting an image using asymptote in an article using pdf latex

Tags: graphics, texstudio, 3d, asymptote

I am using TexStudio and would like to insert a 3D interactive image using asymptote. I have found a few examples on how to generate asymptote 3D interactive image using standalone mode. Now, I would like to insert those in a latex document. Asymptote is installed using the MikTex console.

I would like to know,

1. How to include those interactive 3D files into a latex pdf document?
2. If I have to generate the image on the fly while compiling the latex code, what is the best way to do it?

**Info for Q1:** The code that is used for generating the 3D interactive pdf using asymptote.exe is given below.

```
import three;

currentprojection=perspective(300,-650,500);
currentlight.background=paleyellow;

surface carbon=scale3(1)*unitsphere; // 1 pm
surface hydrogen=scale3(1)*unitsphere; // 1 pm

triple px=(1,0,0);
triple py=(0,1,0);
triple pz=(0,0,1);
triple nx=(-1,0,0);
triple ny=(0,-1,0);
triple nz=(0,0,-1);

real d1=10;

triple p1=(0,0,0);
triple p2=p1+px*d1;
triple p3=p2+py*d1;
triple p4=p3+nx*d1;
triple p5=p1+pz*d1;
triple p6=p2+pz*d1;
triple p7=p3+pz*d1;
triple p8=p4+pz*d1;
triple p9=p1+px*d1*0.5+py*d1*0.5+pz*d1*0.5;

pen blue=rgb(0,0.01,0.99);
pen lime=rgb(0.5,0.5,0);
pen green=rgb(0,1,0);

defaultrender=render(compression=Zero,merge=true);

draw(shift(p1)*carbon,blue);
draw(shift(p2)*carbon,blue);
draw(shift(p3)*carbon,blue);
draw(shift(p4)*carbon,blue);
draw(shift(p5)*carbon,blue);
draw(shift(p6)*carbon,blue);
draw(shift(p7)*carbon,blue);
draw(shift(p8)*carbon,blue);
draw(shift(p9)*carbon,green);

pen thick=linewidth(0.3);

draw(p1--p2--p3--p4--cycle,thick);
draw(p5--p6--p7--p8--cycle,thick);
draw(p1--p5,thick);
draw(p2--p6,thick);
draw(p3--p7,thick);
draw(p4--p8,thick);
```

Is there a method by which the pdf generated through the above code could be inserted into an article class document in Latex?

**Info for Q2:** I am trying to insert a simple 2D picture. However, the pdf generated does not contain any graphical elements! The code I am using is given below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
    This is my first experiment.
    \begin{asy}
        settings.outformat="pdf";
        draw((-.1,0) -- (2,0));
        draw((0,-.1) -- (0,2));     
    \end{asy}
\end{document}
```

Can I use the code given for Q1 directly into the latex article class document and generate the direct output? If so, how should the above above program has to be changed? Which method is efficient?

I have installed ghostscript on my windows pc. I am using pdflatex for compiling.

**Update:**
For Q1: What I mean by interactive 'interactive' is a 3d figure that can be allowed to see by rotation using mouse.

For Q2: I have tested my compiling directory and found that filename-1.asy file is getting generated on compiling the code. Wile compiling, the following message is getting generated:

```
return settings.outformat == "html" || settings.outformat=="v3d" || settings.v3d; ^ *\Programs\MiKTeX/asymptote/plain_shipout.asy: 36.79: no matching field of name 'v3d' in 'settings'
```

The commands used for compiling the files are: pdflatex->asy-pdf-chain->pdflatex->compile->view.

**update-2:**
I have uninstalled MikTex, TexStudio, cleaned all the folders and reinstalled it. Now, I do not get the error mentioned preciously.

Now my windows OS contains 2 asymptote setups. One is through the MikTex console another is directly installed. When the tex file is compiled, ide is generating the asy file, but could not compile it and generate the corresponding pdf file to include in the final document. When I have manually double clicked the asymptote file generated by IDE, pdf file could get generated and could get included in the file document.
Thus, the second problem is partially solved.

Following the same procedure, the code in the Q1 is kept in a separate asy file and executed. This resulted in generation of the so called 3d interactive pdf file. When the same code is compiled as a part of tex file, it could generate only 2D figure. What modifications in the code might be required to include in the asy code to have the interactive figure in the final document?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which documentclass do you use?

Comment: Did you run `asy` on the file produced and then recompile the document? That is: compile -> asy on generated `.asy` file(s) -> recompile? [Also not really sure what's mean by 'interactive' here?]

Comment: @cfr The details are updated.

Comment: No idea what `asy-pdf-chain` does, but your code compiles fine if I run `asy <filename>-1.asy` and then recompile. I'm also not sure what `compile` in your chain does. How is that different from `pdflatex`? Here's my build recipe: `pdflatex <filename>` -> `asy <filename>-1.asy` -> `pdflatex <filename>`. That works and I don't get the message you report. Does it work if you compile it directly on the command line with just the `pdflatex` -> `asy` -> `pdflatex` sequence?

Comment: The settings in that message are coming from somewhere and they are not coming from the code you've posted.

Comment: If I wrap your first code block in an `asy` environment and add `pdf` for the output, that works too (though it is not interactive - not sure if it is meant to be or not).

Comment: If you search the Asymptote manual for `v3d`, you can find a list of options for creating and displaying 3d content. For `v3d` it appears you need a format-aware PDF viewer. Since you're on Windows, you might consider PRC instead. I have no idea what the difference is. Since PRC seems to be Adobe-centric and Adobe don't support Linux at all, it's not an option I'd consider, but if you don't want to use a specialist viewer, maybe it's an option.